# Scala code to demonstrate nested scopes behaves differently in Java

Tags: java, scala

I have written a Scala class `Sheltie` to understand how scopes work in Scala. I wrote an equivalent Java Sheltie class just as a cross-reference. This is where I ran into trouble.

In the body of the Scala `Sheltie` class, there is a method call to the method called `bark` and a `println` statement just after the `bark` call. An equivalent method call `bark()` can be placed in the equivalent Java class inside another method, but outside of any method, it understandably complains of `Duplicate method bark()`.

I understand how Java code works, so this behavior (in Java) is not surprising. What perplexes is why Scala behaves the way it does.

What I hope to solve is: Why does Scala allow "calls" in the class body and why it allows one to create another val definition in the if block, when Java does not.

```
Foo.scala

class Sheltie {
  val barkNum = 10

  def bark() {
    //local barkNum of "bark" method
    val barkNum = 20

     if(true){
       //local "barkNum" of if-block
       val barkNum = 30 //why does Scala not complain of a duplicate local variable, when            Java does in the equivalent program Sheltie.java
       println("Inside if block: No of times Riley barked is " + barkNum)
     }

     println("Outside if block: No of times Riley barked is " + barkNum)
  }

  bark //Why does this work, when you can't do this in Java
  println("Outside bark: No of times Riley barked is " + barkNum)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say Scala *allows calls* in the class body, the body is actually the constructor, so this is equivalent to having:

```
public Sheltie()
{
    bark();
    System.out.println("Outside bark: No of times Riley barked is " + barkNum);
}
```

in Java.

Comment: That is it - the body being the constructor itself. Awesome explanation.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala, statements (excluding declarations) "in the class body" are executed as part of the default constructor. You will be able to observe this when you instantiate an object of class `Sheltie`. Additional constructors are called [*auxiliary constructors*](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/steps.html) in Scala.

```
class Test(a: Int) {
  println("a = " + a)
}

new Test(1) /* Prints a = 1 */
```

Regarding variable shadowing, there isn't really a right or wrong thing to do. Scala allows you to shadow variables, other languages don't. My guess is that it is allowed because programming in a functional style often leads to lots of local variables existing in a very limited scope, e.g., from closure declarations.

Comment: Very good explanation. My appreciation to both you and Reimeus for unraveling this. Both are correct answers. You added more detail, but both answers are very informative.

Comment: I wished to set both answers as accepted answers. Unfortunately there is no way to do so?

Comment: You can only accept one answer, but you can upvote multiple answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just complementing about `barkNum`. Scala has simple rules about scoping and declarations. Briefly:

- At the top level, only classes, traits, objects and package objects are allowed.

  - This is a JVM-imposed restriction.
- Any block ({}-delimited code) accepts any kind of declaration.

  - That includes the bodies of classes, traits and objects.
- Inner declarations shadows outer declarations.

Comment: Your additional comments are very much appreciated.

Comment: You are very right. I just read about these precedence rules from Suareth's book and your explanation just made it clearer

Comment: Your second rule explains why I can create a new declaration of barkNum (and not get a complaint from the compiler) inside a if block, simply because that block is between {}